# launch screen for UIDocumentBrowserViewController (dark appearance)

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, launch-screen, uidocumentbrowservc

I'm using a `UIDocumentBrowserViewController` as my initial screen with `browserUserInterfaceStyle = .dark`.

**How can I construct a matching `LaunchScreen.storyboard`?**

I'm trying to follow the HIG: https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/icons-and-images/launch-screen/

I can't directly use `UIDocumentBrowserViewController` in the storyboard (would have been nice!), so I've tried using a `UISplitViewController` but it's difficult to get the appearance correct.

Is there an easy way to do this? If not, what would closely approximate the `UIDocumentBrowserViewController`?